# Lubunut PCManFM not showing correct disk size

Tags: lubuntu, disk, pcmanfm

I am using Lubuntu 18.04, and I recently replaced my old 500GB SSD with a 1 TB SSD. I first used CloneZilla to image the old SSD on the new one, then I used Gparted to resize the new SSD to its full capacity. Everything seems to be working fine, but when I open the file manager it shows that I ave about 15GB left down on the lower right (highlighted in yellow)
[PCManFM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMmEE.png)
I searched for a solution to that issue, but couldn't find something dealing with PCManFM or LVM. Maybe I missed something in my search!

Here is an output when I ran df -h [df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajsEF.png)

and here screenshots of my Disks and GParted respectively [Disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX59V.png) [GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTm35.png)

Appreciate any suggestions.
Cheers!

Comment: You need to use lvm tool to expand the volume inside. You only expanded the container.

Comment: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that 30-April-2021 reached it's EOL.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses  See https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note only supported releases are on-topic here

Comment: Thanks for your input @ChanganAuto. Your suggestion worked! I accept your response as a solution. Not sure how to vote it up. Cheers!